# libGDX : How can I screenshot whole camera scene NOT game scene only?

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, coordinates, screenshot

I know how to take a screenshot of current framebuffer bounds which it takes only the visual drawing pixels on the screen (Game Scene).
For example I draw 15 images as shown.

[image]

**BUT** as you can see only 6 images drawn only, because of FrameBuffer bounds (Game Scene OR Camera Coordinates of game)

**NOW:** I applied the Screenshot code using **prefWidth of scrollpane** which bigger than buffer width to take screenshot with all 15 images as shown code:

```
private Stage stage;
private ScrollPane pane;

@Override
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage();

    Table table = new Table();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        table.add(new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"))).size(100f).grow();

    pane = new ScrollPane(table);
    stage.addActor(pane);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    pane.debugAll();
}


@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
        byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, (int) pane.getPrefWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);

        // This loop makes sure the whole screenshot is opaque and looks exactly like what the user is seeing
        for (int i = 4; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
            pixels[i - 1] = (byte) 255;
        }

        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap((int) pane.getPrefWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(Gdx.files.absolute("E:\\Programs\\" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".png"), pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }
}
```

**But the Result for sure:**
[image]

How can I take 15 images as a screenshot of whole game coordinates (drawing pixels + NOT drawing pixels) without resize the camera !?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would need to create a FrameBuffer that has those dimensions and draw to it using a camera that takes those dimensions into account. But there is a size limit on FrameBuffers depending on the device. Probably safer to take multiple screenshots and stitch them together.

Comment: @Tenfour04 ys, you are right. But can I do that without visual drawing for user? i.e. can I draw pixels into a FrameBuffer behind the game scene !?

Comment: Yes, see the FrameBuffer class in libGDX. It lets you create off-screen frame buffers that you can draw to. I think there are lots of examples of using it you can google.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for quick response. And I think you answered me. You can post your answer to accept it if you want. Thanks again :)